# Get Internet Explorer Script Error when i call selenium.waitForPageToLoad

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, selenium

This is v. frustrating. I get Internet Explorer Script Error modal dialog when i call selenium.waitForPageToLoad(). Below is a snippet of the command sequence.

...
type(short_desc, IE6.0 -- Testcase:SimultaneousEditingConflictDetected...
click(component)
select(component, place holder)
click(commit)
waitForPageToLoad(60000)
...

I turned off all debug or script error report (Tools->i.options->advanced). somehow it still manages to pop up. Anyone knows of any issue with IE and waitforpagetoload?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to start selenium server with admin privileges. Start command prompt as administrator, then start your selenium server. Script error will not show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but not using Selenium, but just with manual use of IE. I found an information somewhere on the internet that I could disable the **Machine Debug Manager** Windows service (not only stop it, but prevent it from starting after the computer restarts).
And that has helped.

Comment: Finally i think i might have an answer to this hell but I cant seem to find this service. I have looked in services.msc and msconfig and still cant find anything with the name Machine Debug Manager or MDM or sort. Only thing i found was 'Visual Studio 2005 Remote Debugger' but it was already disabled. Any idea where i can find this?

Comment: I have a service with the "M.D.M." as the name.
The description is "Supports local and remote debugging for Visual Studio and script debuggers. If this service is stopped, the debuggers will not function properly". The executable is: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG\MDM.EXE". 
I am running Win XP Pro with Office 2003 installed.